# How do i fill ONE cell with a range of dates between a start and end date

Tags: google-sheets

I have a formula which calculates the difference between a start and end date, but each date is displayed in a separate cell. I need all the dates to be in one cell, separated by ",". I know the textjoin() formula can be used for this to a point, but i don't know how to get it to work from dates which aren't already in cells.

***Here is what I have already.***

[image]

the formula in the C2 is `=A2+1` and the formula in the cells below that is `=IF($A$2+ROW(A2)>=$B$2-1,"",C2+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ***Microsoft-365*** you may use below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,TEXT(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),SEQUENCE(DAY(B2)-DAY(A2)-1,,DAY(A2)+1)),"M/d/yyyy"))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this on Excel Online?

Comment: I get the error "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type."

The same formula in google sheets gives the error "Function SEQUENCE parameter 2 value is 0. It should be greater than or equal to 1." if this helps

Comment: If you are in **google-sheet** then try `=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,TEXT(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),SEQUENCE(DAY(B2)-DAY(A2)-1,1,DAY(A2)+1)),"M/d/yyyy")))`.

Comment: Sorry @Harun24HR, but doesn't this only work for days in the same month? Suggest just =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,TEXT(SEQUENCE(B2-A2-1,,A2+1),"M/d/yyyy"))

Comment: @TomSharpe Yes. I given solution just based on given data. Anyway thanks for your suggest.